# CSS Bootstrap two column layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout

Do you have any idea how to do this layout using bootstrap?

[click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvxqR.png)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `bootstrap 4+`

try this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
     <img src="your path">
   </div

   <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
     your text goes here
   </div
</div>
```